# sipunit rejecting rejecting Messages

Tags: mobicents

I am using SipUnit 2.0 for my framework and currently I am stuck with the following. Would appreciate any help.

As to my knowledge, sipUnit creates sipphone, with address in the format of user@domain, and the stack filters out the incoming messages to the sipphone based on the Request URI or the TO address with its contact address.

But my current scenario is that the sipUnit Stack is receiving INVITE messages in the format INVITE sip:domain:port

Is there any way to work around it?

Thanks and regards,
Nilim